# How to use Math.sin with 2x, in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, solver

Hi I am working on an expression solver. It solves this:

[image]

Everything has been working fine, expect for when I got to the sin of 2x. Math.sin(2x) returns an error, and I am not sure how to find this.
Thanks,

Comment: Did you use the `*` to multiply, `Math.sin(2*x)`?

Comment: The comment above is the key.  Your new information doesn't change that.  Shouldn't solve equations you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is some variable, you are multiplying it by 2. in javascript, that looks like:

```
2*x
```

so sin(2x) becomes:

```
Math.sin(2*x)
```